# Read SAML User ID after login from Okta using django,python

Tags: python, django, saml-2.0, okta

I have used the django-saml2-auth - https://pypi.org/project/django-saml2-auth/ library to login into my django application from Okta.

Post successful login into okta, when I click on my application's tab I even get redirected to my application's login page.
I want to read the User name using which the user logged into Okta and validate it and redirect the user to my home page and not login screen. The issue is I'm not able to retrieve the user name for Okta Login.

I have also installed SAML Tracer in Firefox and there I am able to see Username. I don't know how to fetch it in python.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `TRIGGER.BEFORE_LOGIN` in the `SAML2_AUTH` settings to a [function](https://github.com/fangli/django-saml2-auth/blob/825c1092803c38f626089763a7a3e030f2f82c1d/django_saml2_auth/views.py#L185) path that accepts a dictionary of values. In that dictionary, you'll have access to the user info sent by Okta if you've correctly set the attributes statements mapping on the Okta app. The [same trigger function](https://github.com/k6io/django-saml2-auth/blob/534dfcdd36484e82e8bfaee0d7189e9379bbaef2/django_saml2_auth/views.py#L86) can be passed to the maintained version of django-saml2-auth. I recommend you to use the [maintained version of the library](https://github.com/k6io/django-saml2-auth).